# Objective C: Atomic decrement of integer without @synchronized?

Tags: objective-c, properties, atomic, race-condition, synchronized

If I use

```
@property (atomic,assign) int value;
```

and later access it like so

```
self.value--;
```

is that decrement atomic? Because if I had to do this:

```
self.value = self.value - 1;
```

then I am sure there would be a chance of a race condition between the read and the write.

My instinct of course is to just do this

```
@synchronized(self) { value--; }
```

but I am being told that is not kosher.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Try OSAtomicIncrement and OSAtomicDecrement as described in [this article from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW14).

```
self.value = self.value - 1;
```

will not be atomic regardless of how the property is defined.

Comment: Cool. (upvoted.) I did not know about those atomic operations. Much cleaner than dealing with locks for something as simple as an increment.

Comment: Just be aware that _everybody_ writing to the value must use the same style of atomic operation. If your thread uses OSAtomicIncrement and mine uses @synchronized (self) { self.value += 1; } it won't work. Probably best to make it a read-only property with a method which performs an atomic add.